# Error: A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff when getting result

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am getting an error when I hit a specific post in Facebook:

Here is the code to run: Just replace to token with yours...

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(yourTokenHere);
var result = client.Batch(
                new FacebookBatchParameter(HttpMethod.Get, "/198907640664_196037430420783"),
                new FacebookBatchParameter(HttpMethod.Get, "/198907640664_196037430420783/comments", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "limit", 20 } }) { Data = new { name = "myposts", omit_response_on_success = false } }
            );
```

The error received is:

> Error: A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff).
>   Parameter name: utf32

The stack trace is:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff).
>   Parameter name: utf32
>      at System.Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32 utf32)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseString(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseObject(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseArray(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseObject(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseObject(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseArray(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseObject(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.TryDeserializeObject(String json, Object& object)
>      at SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(String json)
>      at Facebook.JsonSerializer.SimpleJsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(String json)
>      at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessBatchResult(Object result)
>      at Facebook.FacebookClient.Batch(FacebookBatchParameter[] batchParameters)

I do get this error with other calls as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Invalid/incorrect encoding? ;-) However, this doesn't help with "how to fix".

Comment: Anybody else getting this error? I think the codes that makes it crash are: \udbb8\udf27\udbb8\udf27\udbb8\udf27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that Prabir (The Man of the Facebook C# SDK) have released a new version of SimpleJson v0.7 containing this bug fix. http://simplejson.codeplex.com/releases/view/69446

and also updated the SimpleJson in Facebook C# SDK to v0.7 http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/4f05d3ba8c17

I have tried it and it works fine!

Thanks Prabir